# Passing a dynamically allocated 2d character array to a function

Tags: c++, c, arrays

Here is how the array is allocated.

```
char** cArray =  malloc(10 * sizeof(char *)); 

int i;
for(i =0; i< 10; i++) { 
  cArray[i] = malloc(25 * sizeof(char));
}
```

How to pass into function with this signature:

```
sampleFunction(int max, char list[][max]){
  //Do something
};
```

Tried:

```
sampleFunction(25, cArray);
```

This gives me the following error:

```
expected 'char (*)[(sizetype)(max)]' but argument is of type 'char **'
```

I have also tried:

```
sampleFunction(int max, char* list[][max]){
  //Do something
};

sampleFunction(25, &cArray);
```

This gives me the following error:

```
expected 'char * (*)[(sizetype)(max)]' but argument is of type 'char ***'
```

I have also tried:

```
sampleFunction(int max, char* list[][max]){
  //Do something
};

sampleFunction(25, cArray);
```

This gives me the following error:

```
expected 'char * (*)[(sizetype)(max)]' but argument is of type 'char **'
```

What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: *"What is the correct way to do this?"* -- using `std::vector` and `std::string`.

Comment: Are you using C or C++?  If you are using C++ `std::vector<std::string>` is the preferred method.

Comment: The first step in "the correct way to do this" is to start by specifying which language you are using; C is not the same language as C++. Also, please include the libraries/headers that you're using.

Comment: `char**` is not the same as `char[][]`, and even then `sampleFunction(int **max**, char list[][**max**]){` Array sizes must be constant and known at compilation time in order for the compiler to get the indexing arithmetic right. there is no way `max` can meet these requirements because you can always call the function with a different value.

Comment: @user4581301 variable size arrays *are* supported in C (from C99).

Comment: I stand corrected. The use of `malloc` pushes this question further in the direction of C than C++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arrays are not pointers, and pointers are not arrays.

The first parameter type says that `list` is a pointer to an array of `char`.
`cArray` isn't; it's a pointer to `char*`.

The second says that `list` is a pointer to an array of `char*`, which is even further from `cArray`.

You need to pass the correct type, `char**`, and both dimensions:

```
void sampleFunction(int max_rows, int max_columns, char** list){
    for (int i = 0; i < max_rows; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < max_columns; j++)
            list[i][j] = 0;
}

sampleFunction(10, 25, cArray);
```